# (C) scanf not working when the terminate value is [^\n]

Tags: c, scanf

I am creating a program where you can execute terminal commands via the program. I want to access a directory (using cd /Users/user/Desktop) but since scanf terminates at a whitespace, I was forced to change the terminate value to `[^\n]`. That's when the error popped up. Whenever I enter in a command, it executes said command, but then the next time the program goes through the (infinite) loop, it doesn't stop executing the line before the scanf function. This hasn't happened when the terminate value was `%s`. 
Here is the code for the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void execute(){
    char* command = (char *) malloc(15);
    char* output = (char *) malloc(4096);
    printf(">> ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", command);            //Here is the scanf function
    FILE* cmd = popen(command, "r");
    fread(output, sizeof(output), 32000, cmd);
    if (strlen(output) != 0){
        printf("\n%s\n", output);
    }
    free(output);
    pclose(cmd);
}

int main(){
    while (1){
        execute();
    }
}
```

Here is the output when the terminate value is `[^\n]`:

```
>> ls

Applications
Desktop
Documents
//Here the rest of the contents in my user folder appear (twice for some reason, that's also an issue related to this).

>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
// This then goes on forever
```

and here is the output when the terminate value is `%s`:

```
>> ls

Applications
Desktop
Documents
//Here the rest of the contents in my user folder appear (once)

>> //Here I can input things again
```

Could someone show me how to fix this? (I tried `gets()`, same outcome)

Comment: Serket, do not append your fix here.  You can post it as you own answer below.  Post rolled-back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're telling `scanf` not to read the `\n`, it's leaving it in stdin, so when the loop repeats, it's still there and causes the next iteration to immediately return an empty string. To fix it, a few choices:

- Change `"%[^\n]"` to `" %[^\n]"` to ignore leading whitespace.
- Add `getchar();` after `scanf("%[^\n]", command);` to consume the newline.
- Use `fgets` or some other reading function other than `scanf`. (Not `gets`; it can't be used safely!)

You're also not checking whether `scanf` returned anything, so if it failed to parse anything at all, then you're passing uninitialized memory to `popen`.

Side note: there's lots of other bugs in your program, but they're not relevant to your immediate problem:

1. You leak the memory of `command` each time through your loop. To fix it, add `free(command);` somewhere after the `popen` and before the end of the function.
2. You didn't pass a maximum field width to `scanf`, so if you enter more than 14 characters, you'll have a buffer overflow and corrupt memory. To fix it, change `%[^\n]` to `%14[^\n]` (14 and not 15 so there's room for the null terminator). You should also detect the case of a partial read and handle it properly, to avoid `echo Their alarm is set` from deleting files called `is` and `set`, for example.
3. `sizeof(output)` will be the size of the pointer, not of the memory you allocated that it points to, and `32000` seems to have come out of thin air. Change `sizeof(output)` to 1 and `32000` to `4096`.
4. `fread` doesn't null-terminate its output, so printing it with `%s` will print uninitialized memory after it. To fix it, either use something other than `fread` to get the output, or use its return value and make sure you only print that many characters.

---

With your "fixed" version, there's still a few more problems:

- Your first `fgets` won't buffer-overflow now, but overly-long strings will still cause problems. In particular, if a user enters a command that's too long, it will act as if they hit Enter in the middle of it, resulting in two partial commands being ran.
- Doing `cd` in a subprocess doesn't affect the parent process or any other subprocesses. To make it work, you'd need to check to see if the command they entered starts with `cd`, and if so, call [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) directly instead of doing `popen`.

---

Here's a way that works right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    char *command = NULL;
    size_t commandsize = 0;
    char *output = (char *)malloc(5000);
    while(1){
        printf(">> ");
        ssize_t commandlen = getline(&command, &commandsize, stdin);
        if(commandlen < 0) {
            // assume EOF. Small chance that it was an error though
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", command);
        if(!strcmp(command, "exit\n")) {
            break;
        }
        if(!strncmp(command, "cd ", 3)) {
            command[commandlen - 1] = '\0'; // remove the newline
            if(chdir(command + 3)) {
                perror("chdir");
            }
            continue;
        }
        FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");
        if(!cmd) {
            perror("popen");
            continue;
        }
        size_t sz;
        while ((sz = fread(output, 1, 5000, cmd)) > 0){
            fwrite(output, 1, sz, stdout);
        }
        pclose(cmd);
    }
    free(command);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

A few notes about it:

- Instead of `malloc` and `free`ing stuff every time through the loop, I moved those variables up to function-scope so it only happens once the whole time the program's running.
- I use `getline` to read the whole line, and automatically allocate however much space is necessary. This, like `popen`, isn't part of standard C but is part of POSIX.
- I use `fread` and `fwrite` to shuttle data from the process we started, to avoid having to think about null terminators. I assume you're eventually going to do some sort of processing on this data; if not, consider using `system` instead of `popen`, which will automatically write the output back to the user.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point out the other bugs to me as I'm relatively new to C?

Comment: @Serket don't use scanf, don't forget to dealloc(free) a memory field allocated already.

Comment: @Serket I added details of the bugs that jumped out at me.

Comment: I have a new issue that I would really appreciate if you could help me with: For some reason, I cannot change directory (cd). Why is that? I've added the new code to the question.

Comment: @Serket Another edit to address that coming up briefly.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have posted the fixed code as an answer, could you modify it so the ```cd``` command would work (the answer has been removed from the question)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica How should I fix the command length issue? (I could just increase the maximum command length, is that the solution?)

Comment: @Serket No, it isn't. You can't make it infinitely long, so no matter how long you make it, someone else could just enter something longer. Another edit coming up...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the fixed code (other than the `cd` issue) (Another user has posted the final version of the code. Their answer has been marked as the correct answer).  **IGNORE THE FOLLOWING CODE, IT IS NO LONGER RELEVANT**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    while(1){
        char* command = (char *) malloc(30);
        char* output = (char *)  malloc(5000);
        printf(">> ");
        fgets(command, 30, stdin);
        printf("%s", command);
        FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");
        while (fgets(output, 5000, cmd) != NULL){
            printf("%s", output);
        }
        pclose(cmd);
        free(command);
        free(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `'\n'` in `command` causes trouble with `popen(command, "r");`  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't think it will. `popen` passes its argument to `/bin/sh -c`, and the shell should just swallow that extra `\n`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Perhaps so. IDK. Code should check the return value of `popen()` before using it in `fgets()` thought, in case things did not work.